# Calculating new form loaction

Tags: vb.net

I have form with button "btn_email".

By pressing to this button I would like new (non modal) form to be opened below that button and right aligned with him.

```
Dim eform As New frm_iemail
With eform
    .Location = ?
    .Show(Me)
End With
```

Which is the best way to calculate this (described) position of new form?
How this calculation should look like?

EDIT after Maurice's solution:

```
Dim eform As New frm_iemail
With eform
    .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    .Location = New Point((Me.Left + btn_email.Left + Button1.Width), (Me.Top + btn_email.Top))
    .Show(Me)
End With
```

Approach2:

```
Dim BorderWidth As Integer = (Me.Width - Me.ClientSize.Width) / 2
Dim TitlebarHeight As Integer = Me.Height - Me.ClientSize.Height - 2 * BorderWidth
.DesktopLocation = New Point((Me.Left + Button1.Left + Button1.Width + BorderWidth), (Me.Top + TitlebarHeight + BorderWidth + Button1.Top))
```

My solution:

```
Dim BorderWidth As Integer = SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width
Dim TitlebarHeight As Integer = SystemInformation.CaptionHeight + BorderWidth
Dim distance As Integer = 3

Dim eform As New frm_iemail
With eform
    .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    .FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    .Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + btn_email.Location.X + btn_email.Width + BorderWidth - .Width, TitlebarHeight + Me.Location.Y + btn_email.Location.Y + btn_email.Height + distance)
    .Show(Me)
End With
```

Final solution:

```
.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + btn_email.Right + BorderWidth - .Width, TitlebarHeight + Me.Location.Y + btn_email.Bottom + distance)
```

Comment: Can you add a simple whiteboard image indicating the button and the position of the form where it should be placed?

Comment: This is basically what you have to do. The only bit which might be improved is replacing btn_email.Location.X + btn_email.Width with btn_email.right (as shown in my answer).

Comment: @Maurice, sorry, I can't make images now, but situation is self descriptable enough.

Comment: @varocarbas, thanks, until now I never uses .right and .bottom! That shorted code a bit.

Comment: You are welcome. Honestly, Right and Bottom represent concepts which I rarely agree with, but have to recognise that are useful for location purposes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below locates the form below the button and right-aligns both controls. What I understand with right-aligning is: right side of `eform` with same Y value than right side of `btn_email`:

```
With eform
    .Show(Me)
    .Location = New Point(Me.Left + btn_email.Right - .Width, Me.Top + btn_email.Bottom + btn_email.Height)
    .BringToFront()
End With
```

NOTE: there might be a small gap depending upon the type of form (e.g., borders); but this has already been taken care of by another answer (and by the last update in your question).

Comment: Yes, that is right aligned. I just add a borders to this solution and this is now OK.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is C# but it should be enough to implement your vb.net solution.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create and show the form
        Form1 form = new Form1();            
        form.Show();

        // Caculate thicknesses of border and titlebar
        int borderWidth = (this.Width - this.ClientSize.Width) / 2;
        int titlebarHeight = this.Height - this.ClientSize.Height - 2 * borderWidth;

        // Calculate the form position
        var x = this.Left + button1.Left + button1.Width + borderWidth - form.Width;
        var y = this.Top + titlebarHeight + borderWidth + button1.Top + button1.Height;

        // Position the form
        form.DesktopLocation = new Point(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Maurice, I added your solution to question. This opens a form right and something up from a button. Something is obviously missing.

Comment: C# is not a problem, but calculation missed!

Comment: @user973238 I've taken the border and titlebar into account :)

Comment: OK Maurice but this don't place a form where it should be. I update question to see what do I get. Just thought that maybe it can be done at more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Dim eform As New frm_iemail
With eform
    .Location = new point(Me.Location.X + btn_email.Location.X + btn_email.Width, Me.Location.Y + btn_email.Location.Y + btn_email.Height)
    .Show(Me)
End With
```

Comment: Hi matzone, again something upper and much right. Can forms border and caption be involved here?